# CSS & jQuery - Click through image, but do register hovering

Tags: css, hover, click-through, pointer-events

I have an image at the bottom of my page (or actually, window) and it is like a rising building.

However, sometimes it overlaps page and/or footer content.
This isn't a really big problem since I just added `pointer-events: none;`.

But I wanted to, when hovered over the image fade it out a bit so it's more obvious you can click through. But because `pointer-events: none;` it doesn't even register the hover action...

Is there any way I can make it click through, but actually catching the hover-trigger?

Thanks in advance!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZqQc/3/)

P.S. Just wondering, is there any way to actually detect hover on only the *non-transparant* parts of the PNG image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my go at it: http://jsfiddle.net/tZqQc/7/

I did the hover events on the `<p>` tag instead, but I think I got the same effect you wanted.

The key is the jQuery code:

```
$("p").mouseenter(function() {
    $( "#theimg" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.2, function() {});
});

$("p").mouseleave(function() {
    $( "#theimg" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 1.0, function() {});
});
```

and as for the transparent hover question, you technically can do it with imagemapping.. but that's a lot of work for this picture (it's probably not worth it)!

Comment: While I would still like it _above_ the text _(so I just added `z-index: 2;` and `pointer-events: none;`)_, it works fine! I don't know why I didn't think of this simple solution... However, I'd actually also like it to fade out on hover, because there isn't always an actual element behind it, but it's suitable for my goal. Thanks!